# Objective-C: Passing an IF statement as a argument

Tags: objective-c

I need to pass an IF statement to a method. In JavaScript you can assign a function to a variable. Then that variable can be passed to a function and executed. Does this exist in Objective-C?

This is the pattern I'd like to implement:

```
-(void)singleComparisonWith:(NSArray *)data
                 IndexBegin:(NSUInteger)indexBegin
                   IndexEnd:(NSUInteger)indexEnd
                  Threshold:(float)threshold {

    NSIndexSet *set1 = [self searchWithData:data
                                      Range:[self makeInspectionWithRange:indexBegin
                                                                      End:indexEnd]
                                     Option:NSEnumerationConcurrent
                                 Comparison:XXXXXXXXX];
// XXXXXXXXX is an IF statement that looks for value at an index above threshold
}

-(void)rangeComparisonWith:(NSArray *)data
                IndexBegin:(NSUInteger)indexBegin
                  IndexEnd:(NSUInteger)indexEnd
              ThresholdLow:(float)thresholdLow
             ThresholdHigh:(float)thresholdHigh {

    NSIndexSet *candidates = [self searchWithData:data
                                               Range:[self makeInspectionWithRange:indexBegin
                                                                               End:indexEnd]
                                              Option:NSEnumerationReverse
                                          Comparison:YYYYYYYYY];
// YYYYYYYYY is an IF statement that looks for value at an index above thresholdLow and above thresholdHigh
}

-(NSIndexSet *)searchWithData:data
                        Range:(NSIndexSet *)range
                       Option:(NSEnumerationOptions)option
                   Comparison:(id)comparison {

    return [data indexesOfObjectsAtIndexes:range
                                   options:option
                               passingTest:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){
// Comparison is used here. Returns YES if conditions(s) are met.
                               }
            ];
}
```

**EDIT:**

Here's the solution thanks to @Charles Srstka.

```
NSIndexSet *set1 = [self searchWithData:data
                                  Range:[self makeInspectionWithRange:indexBegin
                                                                  End:indexEnd]
                                 Option:NSEnumerationConcurrent
                             Comparison:BOOL^(id o) {
                                return ([o floatValue] > threshold);
                             }
                    ];


-(NSIndexSet *)searchWithData:data
                        Range:(NSIndexSet *)range
                       Option:(NSEnumerationOptions)option
                   Comparison:(BOOL(^)(id o))comparison {

    return [data indexesOfObjectsAtIndexes:range
                                   options:option
                               passingTest:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){
                                   return comparison(obj);
                               }
            ];
```

No errors in that segment.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: what about predicates?  I dont know objectiveC but i guess it exists https://medium.com/the-traveled-ios-developers-guide/nspredicate-objective-c-c745f227df87  I have been using it on other occasions and it is very flexible.

Comment: See [Declaring and Creating Blocks](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxDeclaringCreating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH4-SW3) in [Blocks Programming Topics](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH1-SW1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want in Objective-C is called *block syntax*. While certainly not the nicest thing to look at, or the easiest thing to remember, it will do what you want.

```
// declares a block named 'foo' (yes, the variable name goes inside the parens)
NSUInteger (^foo)(NSString *) = ^(NSString *baz) {
    return [baz length];
};

// now you can call foo like a function:
NSUInteger result = foo(@"hello world");

// or pass it to something else:
[someObject doSomethingWith:foo];

// A method that takes a block looks like this:
- (void)doSomethingWith:(NSUInteger (^)(NSString *))block;
```

[This site](http://goshdarnblocksyntax.com/) is a handy "cheat sheet" that lists all the ways to declare a block in Objective-C. You will probably be referring to it often. The URL I linked to is a newer, work-friendly mirror. I'm sure you can guess the site's original URL if you think about it. ;-)

Basically whenever you see a `^` in Objective-C, you're looking at a block declaration. Unless, of course, you're looking at an XOR operation. But usually it's a block.

**EDIT:** Look at the site I linked to, where it says "as an argument to a method call." You need to declare it using that syntax, i.e.

```
... comparison: ^BOOL(id o) {
    return ([o floatValue] > threshold);
}];
```

I know it's not the most intuitive syntax in the world, which is why that site is useful as a cheat sheet.

Also, unrelated to your issue, but Objective-C naming convention is to start the argument labels with lower-case letters; i.e. `range:`, `options:`, and `comparison:` rather than `Range:`, `Option:`, `Comparison:`.

Comment: Those of us who are Smalltalk fans think blocks look just fine, thanks. :-)

Comment: Ok. So would my specific implementation look something like this?
````NSIndexSet *set1 =...````
````Option:NSEnumerationConcurrent````
````Comparison:^BOOL (id *o) {return [o floatValue] > threshold; } ];````

````-(NSIndexSet *)searchWithData...````
````.    Option:(NSEnumerationOptions)option````
````.    Comparison:(BOOL (^)(id *))comparison {````
````...````
```.        passingTest:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){````
````                        return [comparison: obj];````
````         }];````

Comment: @DataZombies Well, unless you're planning to return something by reference, you probably want plain old `id` instead of `id *`. Also, blocks get called like C functions. No square brackets. Honestly, though, the thing I'd probably do would be just to declare your block as `BOOL (^)(id, NSUInteger, BOOL *)`, ignore the second and third arguments, and just pass that sucker straight in.

Comment: Try that out for size.